# angular2 app crashing on IE 11

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am facing one app crash issue in ie11. App is working fine with all browsers but IE.
on some post I found to uncomment the following lines in polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

After un-commenting these lines application is working on IE 11.0.38 (KB203621).
But it is still crashing on IE 11.0.96 (KB4040685). Browser itself stops working while trying to load the app.

If anybody have faced this kind of issue before, please provide your valuable suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: IE is very annoying to use with angular apps, its best to use chrome as it has more compatibility so will therefore crash less. There could also possibly be a bug in that version of IE or something the polyfills dont support yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most ES6 features are not supported in IE 11.

take a look at this to get an idea https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: so what is the solution now? What else Should I implement to make this app work on IE 11?